# Is it possible using NLP? Natural Language processing

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp, nlp, pycorenlp

I have a set of Project Names, a set of keywords and a set of paragraphs.

Now my task is, to check whether keywords match any project names , and keywords match any word in any paragraph.

If any set of paragraphs are matched with a keyword and any project matched with same keyword, then I have to assign these paragraphs to that project.

I have been using String Regex for this. But can this be implemented using Natural Language Processing concepts.

If yes... Please let me know how can it be implemented. It would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check reverse indexing, all the functionalities are available with Elastic search.

Answer (score 3):

There's no NLP involved in this as such.
 No matter what you do, you must have to go through all the projects and all the paragraphs at least once. 
Yes, you can optimize your process by using `hashmaps` or `dictionaries` but at the end of the day, you will be searching and matching strings no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `dictionaries` as mapping becomes easy with the help of dictionaries and regex will be in action too.